# Splitting this string to get the max count to a corresponding character

Tags: java, string, run-length-encoding

I am currently implementing Run Length Encoding for text compression and my algorithm does return Strings of the following form:

Let's say we have a string as input

```
"AAAAABBBBCCCCCCCC"
```

then my algorithm returns

```
"1A2A3A4A5A1B2B3B4B1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C"
```

Now I want to apply Java String split to solve this, because I want to get the highest number corresponding to character. For our example it would be

```
"5A4B8C"
```

My function can be seen below

```
public String getStrfinal(){

    String result = "";
    int counter = 1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("");
    for (int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1)) {
            counter++;
            sb.append(counter);
            sb.append(c);
        }
        else {
            counter = 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    result = sb.toString();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I have an updated answer which takes care of numbers in the line of string have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String getStrfinal(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    char last = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        if(i > 0 && last != str.charAt(i)) {
            sb.append(count + "" + last);
            last = 0;
            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            count++;
        }

        last = str.charAt(i);

    }
    sb.append(count + "" + last);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of string Buffer you can use a map it will be much easier and clean to do so.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {   
    String input = "AAAAABBBBCCCCCCCCAAABBBDDCCCC";
    int counter=1;
    for(int i=1; i<input.length(); i++) {
        if(input.charAt(i-1)==input.charAt(i)) {
            counter=counter+1;
        }else if(input.charAt(i-1)!=input.charAt(i)){
            System.out.print(counter+Character.toString(input.charAt(i-1)));
            counter=1;
        }if(i==input.length()-1){
            System.out.print(counter+Character.toString(input.charAt(i)));
        }
    }   
}
```

This will gives

```
5A4B8C3A3B2D4C
```

**UPDATES**
I Agree with @WJS if the string contains number the out put becomes messy 
hence if the System.out in above code will be exchange with below i.e.

```
System.out.print(Character.toString(input.charAt(i-1))+"="+counter+" ");
```

then for input like

```
AAAAABBBBCCCCCCCCAAABBBDD556677CCCCz
```

we get out put as below

```
A=5 B=4 C=8 A=3 B=3 D=2 5=2 6=2 7=2 C=4 z=1
```

Comment: you can accept the answer if you think it gives you a clean and better solution.

Comment: Your answer fails for `AAAAABBBBCCCCCCCCAAA`. He's trying to do a compression algorithm.   Your method gives `8A4B8C` and would be expanded to `AAAAAAAABBBBCCCCCCCC`.

Comment: @WJS i have done the rectifications :) Thanks I didn't notice its and compression logic.

Comment: Updated print statement needs to be added at two places with appropriate charAt adjustment. Solves the digit problem I mentioned.

Comment: @WJS I did see the updates the example AAAAABBBBCCCCCCCCAAABBBDD556677CCCCz it has number also and the result has been taken care of using the print statement which I have specified to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution.  It starts with the raw string and simply iterates thru the string.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String input = "AAAABBBCCCCCCCDDDEAAFBBCD";
      int index = 0;
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      while (index < input.length()) {
         int count = 0;
         char c = input.charAt(index);
         for (; index < input.length(); index++) {
            if (c != input.charAt(index)) {
               count++;
            }
            else {
               break;
            }
         }
         sb.append(Integer.toString(count));
         sb.append(c);
         count = 0;
      }
      System.out.println(sb.toString());
   }
```

But one problem with this method and others is what happens if there are digits in the text?  For example.  What if the string is `AAABB999222AAA` which would compress to `3A2B39323A`. That could also mean `AAABB` followed by `39 3's` and `23 A's`

Comment: I have updated my answer for the same (including number count), do have a look if its okay

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the possible solutions to your question. We can use a LinkedHashMap data structure which is similar to HashMap but it also maintains the order. So, we can traverse the string and store the occurrence of each character as Key-value pair into the map and retrieve easily with its maximum occurrence.

```
public String getStrFinal(String str){
    if(str==null || str.length()==0) return str;
    LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(); // to store the final string
    for(char ch:str.toCharArray()){
        map.put(ch,map.getOrDefault(ch,0)+1);  // put the count for each character
    }
    for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){  // iterate the map again and append each character's occurence into stringbuilder
        sb.append(entry.getValue());
        sb.append(entry.getKey());
    }

    System.out.println("String = " + sb.toString()); // here you go, we got the final string
    return sb.toString();
}
```